# Can't write file in USB flash drive with Xamarin Android/Uwp

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.uwp, unauthorizedaccessexcepti, usb-flash-drive

I have some troubles. 
It's about this subject => `System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path “/storage/[Name]/[nameFolder]/[fileName].txt is denied.
At System.IO.FileStream etc….`

I know this subject is already here in SOF, but I can't find a solution for Xamarin.Android. It's the same for Xamarin.Uwp, no access right.

I can't write a file in the root path (from the USB Flash Drive path) =

> /storage/[NameOfTheFlashDrive]

It's the same if I use the Android path =

> content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/documents/[NameOfTheFlashDrive]

Same message > System.UnauthorizedAccessException Access to the path

I don't know how to proceed.

I have used =

> File.WriteAllText(filePath, Data);

And I have the permissions to write file in external storage.

The only solution is to use `Plugin.Essential` or `PickerFile` and save manually in the correct path.

If someone have a idea to proceed with the right way.

Thank you.
Zebiphire.

Answer (score 0):

> I have some troubles. It's about this subject => System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path “/storage/[Name]/[nameFolder]/[fileName].txt is denied.
>   At System.IO.FileStream etc….

According to your error message, I guess that you ma need to enbale permission  in runtime.

You should enable **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** and **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permissions in Android and UWP.

Comment: Yes exactly. In the manifest and in the mainActivity. 
If not ! => ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 0);

Comment: With permission I can't write on the flash drive.

Comment: There are some error message? If not, it means that you have read an write permission, so please provide code about writing data on the flash drive here.